# Distinct E,F within a A,B,C, D grouping?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to identify occurences where there are more than 1 distinct value of an E,F column combination within an A,B,C,D grouping.

For example, given the following data:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable   

A          B          C          D          E          F
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1          1          1          1          A          B         
1          1          1          1          A          B         
1          1          1          2          A          C         
1          1          1          2          A          D
```

I want to return

```
A          B          C          D          
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------     
1          1          1          2
```

..because there ar multiple distinct (E,F) combinations within that (A,B,C,D) grouping).

Here's teh SQL to create your test case!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [A] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [B] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [C] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [D] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [E] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [F] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]([A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F])
SELECT N'1         ', N'1         ', N'1         ', N'1         ', N'A         ', N'B         ' UNION ALL
SELECT N'1         ', N'1         ', N'1         ', N'1         ', N'A         ', N'B         ' UNION ALL
SELECT N'1         ', N'1         ', N'1         ', N'2         ', N'A         ', N'C         ' UNION ALL
SELECT N'1         ', N'1         ', N'1         ', N'2         ', N'A         ', N'D         '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    A,B,C,D
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        A,B,C,D,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B,C,D,E,F ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS DistinctTuplesLong,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B,C,D ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS DistinctTuples
    FROM
        Mytable
    ) T
WHERE 
    DistinctTuplesLong < DistinctTuples
```

Edit: used wrong windowing function

Edit 2: clearer now with sample data

Comment: @Velika: I wrote this 30 minutes before your sample data. I guessed basically. But I see my mistake now

Comment: I think both of our answers are still wrong. They both return 2 rows instead of 1 row. I added the additional information to assist people in helping me :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A,B,C,D
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
GROUP BY A,B,C,D
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT E) > 1 OR COUNT(DISTINCT F) > 1
```

Or

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C, D ORDER BY E, F) Rnk
         FROM   [dbo].[MyTable])
SELECT DISTINCT A,
                B,
                C,
                D
FROM   T
WHERE  Rnk = 2
```